# Difference between “lieu” and “endroit”

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

What is the difference between “lieu” and “endroit”? I know both of them mean place, so what exactly is the difference? Please use examples in your answers.

Comment: Please make sure to read the help pages ([on topic questions and how to ask](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [how to answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)). What research have you done, what dictionary have you looked at (Larousse: [endroit](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/endroit/29395), [lieu](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/lieu/47076?q=lieu#47003); you may also try _Collins_, and _TLFi_) and what did you not understand? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually when I say 'lieu', it is like the english 'location', and 'endroit' is like 'spot'. so:

Le lieu est les Caraïbes.

Vas-tu me rencontrer à cet endroit?

I would say 'lieu' is more broad, it's not very specific. I also think it's more formal, I hear it more on the news, than I hear people saying it in real life.
Endroit is like 'spot', or area.

I would say the BIGGEST difference is that lieu is not very commonly used in speech, and endroit is more familiar language.

Answer (score 2):

Lieu as a spot is not used a lot in speech, sometimes in formal situations (news, speeches, ...)

Lieu is rather well-known because used in many expressions:

- en lieu sûr
- cela n'a pas lieu (cela n'arrive pas)
- cela donne lieu (cela entraîne)
- il y a lieu de faire cela (il faut faire cela)
- au lieu de faire cela (à la place de faire cela)
- en dernier lieu (comme dernière solution)

et lieu-dit, non-lieu, lieu commun

à ne pas confondre avec lieue (distance)

- à dix lieues de là, ou à des lieues de là (très loin)
- des bottes de 7 lieues (le petit poucet)

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, when talking about a place, the difference is really a matter of usage, both words can be used and nobody will see anything wrong:

- *J'ai visité l'endroit, j'ai visité les lieux*.
- *Ce n'est pas le lieu, ce n'est pas l'endroit* (meaning it's not the appropriate place to do something).
- *Repérer l'endroit, repérer les lieux* (with a view to doing something).

However there is a small difference: *J'ai visité l'endroit*, refers to the place we are talking about, while *j'ai visité le lieu* implies we are talking about a location where some action took or will take place.

*Avoir lieu* means to take place, and *le lieu de l'action* is where it takes place, shortened into *le lieu*, sometimes *les lieux*.

---

Un *endroit* is a part of something larger, not necessarily a place:

- *Un endroit agréable*: A nice place.
- *Il était au mauvais endroit*: He was at the wrong place.
- *On voit du sable par endroits*: We can see sand in some places. (*Lieu* wouldn't be correct in this sentence.)
- *À quel endroit mettre la chaise?* Where to place the chair?  (*Lieu* wouldn't be correct in this sentence.)
- *Elle a été touchée à plusieurs endroits du corps*: She was hurt at several parts of her body. (*Lieu* wouldn't be correct in this sentence.)

---

*Lieu* is used to denote where some action takes place:

- *Le lieu de naissance*: The place of birth.
- *Un lieu de vacances*: A place used for vacations.
- *Au lieu de vente*: At point of sale.
- *Le lieu de tournage*: The film location.
- *Dresser l'état des lieux*: To perform an assessment, conduct a joint verification. *Endroit* wouldn't be correct in this sentence.)

---

Maybe a good sentence to see the difference is about the place where a murder is committed:

- *L'endroit idéal pour un crime*: The best place for a crime (in general).
- *Le lieu du crime*: The crime scene (the place where the crime took place).

In some cases, *lieu* doesn't refer to any place, but indirectly to the action, and it cannot be replaced by *endroit*:

- *En premier lieu*: In the first place.
- *Au lieu de*: Instead of, as a replacement.
- *Tenir lieu de*: Acting as, replacing.
- *Il n'y a pas lieu de s'inquiéter*: There is no reason to worry about.

*Lieu* comes from latin *locus*, still used in English in math. For example a circle is the locus for points at an equal distance of its center. French equivalent is *lieu*.

Answer (score 0):

un lieu", "une place" and "un endroit" design all a location and in most occasion you can use the one you want without disctinction.

However, they are mostly used for different scale :

"lieu" will mostly be used for larger location like a village, a valley .... It is not so much used in oral modern French.

"place" will be use for the location of the size of one man or one object, a location where an object/a man is/has to be : "This is my spot!" => "C'est ma place!" or "The phone is not where it should" => "Le téléphone n'est pas à sa place". It's also use to design your seat in a plane/train/bus "This is my seat" => "C'est ma place".

But "place" is also the French word for "Plaza", like a big open place without building in a city.

"endroit" will be used for a location at the dimension of a room. Most "place" in English will be translated by endroit : "This is a nice place" => "C'est un endroit agréable". In modern oral French, it case be used for larger location like village/valley.

Source :

https://www.reddit.com/r/French/comments/3bgaaf/whats_the_difference_between_lieu_place_and/

See also the other answers therein.

Comment: Link-only answers are useless if the linked site is not accessible. Please summarise the relevant content in your answer and only provide links as references.